# How to calculate P values in ridge regression in R?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

Following is the example from ?lm.ridge of MASS package:

```
> data(longley) # not the same as the S-PLUS dataset
> names(longley)[1] <- "y"
> lm.ridge(y ~ ., longley)
                        GNP    Unemployed  Armed.Forces    Population          Year      Employed 
2946.85636017    0.26352725    0.03648291    0.01116105   -1.73702984   -1.41879853    0.23128785 
> plot(lm.ridge(y ~ ., longley,
+               lambda = seq(0,0.1,0.001)))
> select(lm.ridge(y ~ ., longley,
+                lambda = seq(0,0.1,0.0001)))
modified HKB estimator is 0.006836982 
modified L-W estimator is 0.05267247 
smallest value of GCV  at 0.0057
```

[image]

How can I calculate P values or confidence intervals like I can get in usual linear regression summary.

Comment: That's a question for Cross Validated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I am concerned `MASS::lm.ridge` does not calculate p-values for your coefficients. You could use the `linearRidge` function from the `ridge` package, however, which does. See the following example:

```
data(longley) 
names(longley)[1] <- "y"

library(ridge)
mymod <- linearRidge(y ~ ., longley)

> summary(mymod)

Call:
linearRidge(formula = y ~ ., data = longley)


Coefficients:
               Estimate Scaled estimate Std. Error (scaled) t value (scaled) Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -1.247e+03              NA                  NA               NA       NA    
GNP           4.338e-02       1.670e+01           3.689e+00            4.526  6.0e-06 ***
Unemployed    1.184e-02       4.286e+00           2.507e+00            1.710   0.0873 .  
Armed.Forces  1.381e-02       3.721e+00           1.905e+00            1.953   0.0508 .  
Population   -2.831e-02      -7.627e-01           5.285e+00            0.144   0.8853    
Year          6.566e-01       1.211e+01           2.691e+00            4.500  6.8e-06 ***
Employed      6.745e-01       9.175e+00           4.996e+00            1.836   0.0663 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Ridge parameter: 0.01046912, chosen automatically, computed using 2 PCs

Degrees of freedom: model 3.67 , variance 3.218 , residual 4.123
```

And using `summary` you get the familiar looking table with your p-values and significance!

Comment: How does one get GCV from this package as one would with `lm.ridge`?

Comment: @SideshowBob As far as I know `linearRidge` does not compute a generalized cross validation metric. And why would you need it anyway? You can use any other package to perform any type of cross validation you want (with the caret package for example).

Comment: Does anyone know why ridge has been [removed from the CRAN repository](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ridge/index.html)?

Comment: @Arne and others coming to this late, the ridge package has been adopted by Steffen Moritz in the last year and re-added to CRAN.